# Primefaces selectonemenu dropdown panel issue

Tags: primefaces, width, selectonemenu

I have a selectonemenu which has list of currency. When i click the menu, In mozilla and IE 11, the width of dropdown is same as the width of selectonemenu

but, when I try to do so in chrome, the panel width is smaller than the selectone menu

Comment: could you please post a screenshot?

Comment: sorry i dont know how to post picture in here.... so i have given the ss link[IMG]http://i.imgur.com/TPt3T25.jpg[/IMG]

Answer (score 1):

Set width in CSS file for class

```
 .ui-selectonemenu-panel {
    width : YOUR_WIDTH !important ;
 }
```

Comment: Try to prevent using !important by making selectors more specific. Read about [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)